# Can I store pointers to C++ classes in C?

Tags: c++, c, extern

How do I store a pointer to a C++ class in a C struct?

I'm working with an API where the basic unit of storage is a C struct (MaxMSP).   I'd like to use C++.  I've attempted to store a pointer to my class in a void* but deleting it (in C++) causes a crash

```
extern "C" void* MyClass_New(){
     MyClass* temp = new MyClass();
     return (void*)temp;
}

extern "C" void MyClass_Delete(void* myclass){
      delete (MyClass*)myclass;  //<--- this line crashes.
}
```

I'm aware this is ugly and dangerous but I don't see another way to do this. do you?

I expected a void* would adequately keep track of a C++ class but calling delete after casting said void* causes a crash.

///////  Here's my minimal reproducible.

.c:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    void* temp;
    temp= MyClassTranslator_New(4);   
    MyClassTranslator_Kill(temp);


    return 0;
}
```

.hpp

```
#ifndef m2ot_base_hpp
#define m2ot_base_hpp


#if defined __cplusplus



extern "C" class MyClassTranslator
{

    private :
        long num;

    public:
        MyClassTranslator(const long num);
        ~MyClassTranslator(){;};
        MyClassTranslator( const MyClassTranslator &obj);


        long getNum(void){return this->num;};


};

extern "C"  void* MyClassTranslator_New(const long num);

extern "C"  void MyClassTranslator_Kill(void* thisc);


#endif

#endif /* m2ot_base_hpp */
```

.cpp

```
MyClassTranslator::MyClassTranslator( const MyClassTranslator &that){
    this->num=that.num;
}

extern "C"  void* MyClassTranslator_New(const long num)
{
    MyClassTranslator* temp= new MyClassTranslator(num);

    return static_cast<void*> (temp);
}

extern "C"  void MyClassTranslator_Kill(void* thisc){
    delete static_cast<MyClassTranslator*>(thisc);
}


MyClassTranslator::MyClassTranslator(const long num){
    this->num=num;
}
```

Comment: I would expect this to work (although pedanticity requires employing `reinterpret_cast`). So, the problem must be in code that's not shown.  Therefore, you will be required [edit] your question, after reading stackoverflow.com's [help] and understand the requirements of providing [mre] that anyone can compile and run for themselves, in order to reproduce your problem. Otherwise, it's not possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: If you simply called `Myclass_New`, and then *immediately* called `MyClass_Delete`, would you get the same issue?  If not, then, as stated, your issue has something to do with the code you're not showing us that happens in-between those calls (like improper pointer / memory management).

Comment: @paul actually that's exactly what I'm doing.  I never wrote a lot of code, it's just a test.

Comment: @sam  I've included the relevant code...  I am a beginner so I very well could have done something stupid.

Comment: Are you in control of the API? If you are, remove `c`. You provide the interface.

Comment: ted, I'm not exactly sure what that means but the API is an SDK for a commercial application, MaxMSP and it's entirely in C.  (I'm a 3rd party dev)

Comment: Then you need to know the internal source code for that class you're creating.  If the constructor and or destructor are faulty, then of course you will get weird behavior, no different if I gave you a class that has a buggy destructor and you call `delete`.

Comment: Also, your code does not really do the minimal.  You have this: `t_matOneToneM2OT *x` -- we have no idea if `x` is valid or not.  If `x` is not pointing to a valid object, then anything you do with `x` is invalid.  What you should do is forget about `x`, and simply call that function (globally), assign the pointer simply, and delete that pointer.

Comment: Are there shared resources involved? A `delete` may call the destructor you compiled but calling the `free` in some library unless you're careful.

Comment: @paul, I've included the entire example.  I was refraining since it includes MaxMSP API code but you can basically skip down to the last function (matOneToneM2OT_test)

Comment: @Audiomatt No, it's not complete. Take away all the code that''s pointless and complete it so we can copy it and complie it without modifications.

Comment: @Audiomatt -- There is no need for all of this code.  You should create a very simple `main` function, and simply make two API function calls -- who cares if the program makes sense or actually does anything meaningful -- all you're testing is whether you can create and destroy that object.

Comment: I apologize.  This is necessary for my runtime environment.  I'll attempt now to build a scratch c++ project.  may take a while as I've actually never done that before.

Comment: @paul.  I've reworked the .c file so it's shorter.  I just threw it in a commandline .c project.  here's the output from xcode:  MiniRepro(17757,0x1000aa5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x505a60: pointer being freed was not allocated
MiniRepro(17757,0x1000aa5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: The code you have posted should give an error for `temp= MidiToOneToneTranslator_New(4);` because no declaration of the function is visible. (You hid the declaration behind `__cplusplus` test).  The segfault is probably a consequence of trying to run erroneous code. If you didn't see an error message then check your compiler settings (or check you actually posted the real code).

Comment: @ted minimized even more.

Comment: @M.M   I'm having a hard time understanding.  Isn't extern "C" supposed to expose the function?

Comment: @Audiomatt in your `.c` file you never include a declaration of the function.  The `extern "C"` lines are only included by your `.cpp` file. You used `#if defined __cplusplus` to make the header look different when included each way.

Comment: I'm assuming the first of the 3 parts of the "minimal" example is a .c file, and the last part is a .cpp file (it would be good to edit the question to clarify this)

Comment: @M.M done.  Apologies again.

Comment: Start here: `int main() { ...code...}`. Make `code` as minimal as possible but enough to reproduce the error. Make it possible for others to copy and compile your code without making changes to it.

Comment: @ted  cut out includes, renamed class.  Can't see it getting farther down.  Like I said, I'm a beginner, looks like our class needs at least a variable, copy, new, and delete. no?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you do it the other way around. Start with an empty `main` and add to it until the problem arises - then, post that code - and all of it, not selected parts.

Comment: @Ted, at the line where I'm calling delete it says  "error for object 0x615550: pointer being freed was not allocated"  but I double checked by printing the temp->getNum() in the _new function and it indeed was allocated.

Comment: I explained the likely problem in my comment above but you seem to have ignored it... in the C file you have not got visible declarations of the functions you are calling. It's REALLY IMPORTANT that if you don't see compiler error messages for this then you fix your compiler settings so that you do.  E.g. you have wasted hours on this when the compiler can tell you about the problem straight away.

Comment: In the latest edit the .cpp file is incorrect because `MyClassTranslator` is not declared. I guess you may have misunderstood the request for minimal code . The code you post MUST reproduce the problem with no modifications. Otherwise people are guessing about what you're actually compiling. The minimal aspect is minimizing the code subject to that constraint.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197471/discussion-on-question-by-audiomatt-can-i-store-pointers-to-c-classes-in-c).

Comment: I would describe the pointers as 'object' or 'instance' pointers, rather than 'class', yes?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I store pointers to C++ classes in C?

Yes.

> but deleting it (in C++) causes a crash

There are a few possibilities:

- You passed a pointer to `MyClass_Delete` that didn't originate from `MyClass_New`.
- You passed the same pointer to `MyClass_Delete` more than once.
- The destructor of the class crashes.

---

Regarding style:

The cast in `MyClass_New` is redundant.

I recommend not using C style cast in C++. You can use `static_cast` to convert from `void*`.

You could use a wrapper such as:

```
struct MyClass_handle {
    void* ptr;
};
struct MyClass_handle MyClass_New();
void MyClass_Delete(struct MyClass_handle myclass);
```

The use of typed handle makes it easier to catch incorrect usage.

Comment: I included my code above.  I don't see myself doing anything this silly but like I said elsewhere, I'm a beginner

Comment: @Audiomatt I don't see anything wrong with your code. I recommend creating a [mcve]

Comment: Included a minimal reproducable.  Forgive the necessary API code in the .c file, the relevant test code is at the bottom.

Comment: @Audiomatt Your example works fine for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SHc57gFPCamsyiR4

Comment: I don't know why, but wandbox may have compiled the C file as C++, considering it doesn't complain of missing function declaration though. I don't know of an  online tool to link together both C and C++

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't seem to work there with clang on wandbox.     I'm running libc++ with c++ 11 support.    I bet it's some esoteric thing in build settings.   ///Wait where's the missing declaration?  Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: @Audiomatt When you changed compiler, it cleared the "Compiler options" dialog, which I'm attempting to use to pass the C source file. When I tried with clang, it gave a clear warning: *"warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]"*. So, as I suspected in GCC's case as well, my demo is not pure reproduction, since the C file is actually not compiled as C.

Comment: @Audiomatt *"Wait where's the missing declaration?"* `MyClassTranslator_New`  and `MyClassTranslator_Kill` are not declared in the C version, as M.M pointed out.

Comment: @Audiomatt I tried it locally, fixed the missing declarations, used actually C, and it still works. (Also, in previous comment I meant to say C source file, not "version").